# Complicated IF ELSE statement

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am not familiar enough with classic ASP/VBScript. I have the below code that is working perfectly for my needs.

The below code is checking if my 3 different cookies are empty and inserts the incoming value to the first available. If all those 3 cookies have values, then the script redirects to somepage.

As I wrote before, this code is working fine, but I need some extra work to do: I want also to check IF my incoming value (which is the string `productID_from_url`) already exists in any of those 3 cookies' values (because I don’t want duplicate values) and if it exists, then to stop the script and redirect the user to somepage.

I want all of them together without losing the functionality of the below code.
Can someone advise me what I have to do?

```
<%
If Request.Cookies("compena") = "" Then
Response.Cookies("compena")=productID_from_url
Response.Redirect(url_epistrofis_epi_tixias)
Else
If Request.Cookies("compdyo") = "" Then
Response.Cookies("compdyo")=productID_from_url
Response.Redirect(url_epistrofis_epi_tixias)
Else
If Request.Cookies("comptria") = "" Then
Response.Cookies("comptria")=productID_from_url
Response.Redirect(url_epistrofis_epi_tixias)
Else
Response.Redirect(url_epistrofis_apo_tixias)
End If
End If
End If
%>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "stop the script and redirect the user to somepage". Your code already has a default redirection when all 3 cookies are empty. Do you want to redirect somewhere else when `productID_from_url is found? Where to?

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers Yes! This is exactly what I need. I need when `productID_from_url' is found in any of those 3 cookies, to redirect the user somewhere else. And if not found to continue doing what already  doing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simplification would be to use `If..ElseIf..Else` instead of nested `If..Else` constructs:

```
If Request.Cookies("compena") = "" Then
    Response.Cookies("compena") = productID_from_url
    Response.Redirect(url_epistrofis_epi_tixias)
ElseIf Request.Cookies("compdyo") = "" Then
    Response.Cookies("compdyo") = productID_from_url
    Response.Redirect(url_epistrofis_epi_tixias)
ElseIf Request.Cookies("comptria") = "" Then
    Response.Cookies("comptria") = productID_from_url
    Response.Redirect(url_epistrofis_epi_tixias)
Else
    Response.Redirect(url_epistrofis_apo_tixias)
End If
```

You could also loop over the cookies you want to check

```
redirected = False
For Each cookie in Array("compena", "compdyo", "comptria")
    If Request.Cookies(cookie) = "" Then
        Response.Cookies(cookie) = productID_from_url
        Response.Redirect(url_epistrofis_epi_tixias)
        redirected = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If Not redirected Then Response.Redirect(url_epistrofis_apo_tixias)
```

but unless you have a lot of values to compare against I'd consider the former easier to understand than the latter.

If you want to redirect to a different location if any of the cookies matches `productID_from_url` the code gets more complicated overall, because you need either additional conditions or an additional loop to check for that *before* checking for empty cookies.

Example using the first approach with a combined check:

```
If Request.Cookies("compena") = productID_from_url Or Request.Cookies("compdyo") = productID_from_url Or Request.Cookies("comptria") = productID_from_url Then
    Response.Redirect(other_redirect_url)
ElseIf Request.Cookies("compena") = "" Then
    Response.Cookies("compena") = productID_from_url
    Response.Redirect(url_epistrofis_epi_tixias)
ElseIf Request.Cookies("compdyo") = "" Then
    Response.Cookies("compdyo") = productID_from_url
    Response.Redirect(url_epistrofis_epi_tixias)
ElseIf Request.Cookies("comptria") = "" Then
    Response.Cookies("comptria") = productID_from_url
    Response.Redirect(url_epistrofis_epi_tixias)
Else
    Response.Redirect(url_epistrofis_apo_tixias)
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I cannot understand where exactly your code checks for duplicates?

Comment: It didn't, because the desired behavior wasn't clear to me. Hence my comment to your question. Updated answer.

Comment: That's what I needed. Your help was life-saving!